# Iterating through the results of the JSON response - Android + Retrofit + Moshi

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, moshi

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "customer_id": 3,
            "service_type_id": 1,
            "full_name": "Teja Babu S",
            "email": "testemail@gmail.com",
camera_types": 1,
            "dvr_types": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-01-04 14:18:30",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-04 14:18:30",
            "camera_type": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Analogue hd",
                "description": null,
                "status": 1,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2020-01-04 08:03:45",
                "updated_at": "2020-01-04 08:54:23"
            },
            "dvr_type": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "XVR - nvr",
                "description": "desc",
                "status": 1,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "created_at": "2020-01-04 08:28:04",
                "updated_at": "2020-01-04 08:57:17"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for converion. I am not pasting the result to keep the question simple.

> package - package
>   com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory.OrderDetail;
>
> ClassName - OrderDetailsResponse
>
> Target language: Java
>
> Source type: JSON
>
> Annotation style: Moshi

I would like to access the Name from Both camera_type and dvr_type

I am using Moshi + retrofit

**OrderDetail**

```
package com.tesmachino.saycure;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tesmachino.saycure.Auth.TokenManager;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory.OrderDetail.OrderDetailsResponse;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory.OrderHistoryResponse;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.UserDetails.UserDetailsGetResponse;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.network.ApiService;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.network.RetrofitBuilder;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class OrderDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    ApiService service;
    TokenManager tokenManager;

    Call<OrderDetailsResponse> call;


    private static final String TAG = "OrderDetail";

    @BindView(R.id.orderdetails_id)
    TextView orderId;

    @BindView(R.id.orderdetails_client_name)
    TextView orderDetailsClientName;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_detail);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        tokenManager = TokenManager.getInstance(getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE));
        service = RetrofitBuilder.createServiceWithAuth(ApiService.class, tokenManager);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {


        //Get the Data from the Intent
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("order_id")) {
            int order_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("order_id", 1);
            Log.d(TAG, "IntentWorking" + order_id);

            call = service.orderDetails(order_id);


            call.enqueue(new Callback<OrderDetailsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<OrderDetailsResponse> call, Response<OrderDetailsResponse> response) {
                    OrderDetailsResponse orderDetails = response.body();

                    if (orderDetails != null){

                    }

                    Log.w(TAG, "onResponse123: " + orderDetails.getData().get(0).getId());

                    Toast.makeText(OrderDetail.this, "" + response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    orderId.setText(String.valueOf(orderDetails.getData().get(0).getId()));
                    orderDetailsClientName.setText(orderDetails.getData().get(0).getFullName());
                    Log.w(TAG, "onResponse45321: "+ orderDetails.getData().get(0).getCameraType());

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<OrderDetailsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(OrderDetail.this, "Failure" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "There seems to be an error while fetching the Order Id. Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**OrderDetailsResponse**

```
package com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory.OrderDetail;

import com.squareup.moshi.Json;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import java.util.List;

public class OrderDetailsResponse {

    @Json(name = "data")
    private List<OrderDetailsGet> data = null;

    public List<OrderDetailsGet> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<OrderDetailsGet> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("data", data).toString();
    }
}
```

**OrderDetailsGet**

```
package com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory.OrderDetail;

import com.squareup.moshi.Json;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

public class OrderDetailsGet {

    @Json(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Json(name = "customer_id")
    private Integer customerId;
    @Json(name = "service_type_id")
    private Integer serviceTypeId;
    @Json(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;
    @Json(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Json(name = "address_line_1")
    private String addressLine1;
    @Json(name = "address_line_2")
    private String addressLine2;
    @Json(name = "phone_no")
    private String phoneNo;
    @Json(name = "alternate_phone_no")
    private Object alternatePhoneNo;
    @Json(name = "land_mark")
    private Object landMark;
    @Json(name = "area")
    private Object area;
    @Json(name = "district")
    private String district;
    @Json(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Json(name = "state")
    private String state;
    @Json(name = "pincode")
    private Integer pincode;
    @Json(name = "type_of_property")
    private Integer typeOfProperty;
    @Json(name = "camera_types")
    private Integer cameraTypes;
    @Json(name = "no_of_cameras")
    private Integer noOfCameras;
    @Json(name = "dvr_types")
    private Integer dvrTypes;
    @Json(name = "dvr_channel")
    private Integer dvrChannel;
    @Json(name = "notes")
    private Object notes;
    @Json(name = "deleted_at")
    private Object deletedAt;
    @Json(name = "created_at")
    private String createdAt;
    @Json(name = "updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;
    @Json(name = "camera_type")
    private CameraType cameraType;
    @Json(name = "dvr_type")
    private DvrType dvrType;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public Integer getServiceTypeId() {
        return serviceTypeId;
    }

    public void setServiceTypeId(Integer serviceTypeId) {
        this.serviceTypeId = serviceTypeId;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return addressLine1;
    }

    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }

    public String getAddressLine2() {
        return addressLine2;
    }

    public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String  phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public Object getAlternatePhoneNo() {
        return alternatePhoneNo;
    }

    public void setAlternatePhoneNo(Object alternatePhoneNo) {
        this.alternatePhoneNo = alternatePhoneNo;
    }

    public Object getLandMark() {
        return landMark;
    }

    public void setLandMark(Object landMark) {
        this.landMark = landMark;
    }

    public Object getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(Object area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Integer getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(Integer pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public Integer getTypeOfProperty() {
        return typeOfProperty;
    }

    public void setTypeOfProperty(Integer typeOfProperty) {
        this.typeOfProperty = typeOfProperty;
    }

    public Integer getCameraTypes() {
        return cameraTypes;
    }

    public void setCameraTypes(Integer cameraTypes) {
        this.cameraTypes = cameraTypes;
    }

    public Integer getNoOfCameras() {
        return noOfCameras;
    }

    public void setNoOfCameras(Integer noOfCameras) {
        this.noOfCameras = noOfCameras;
    }

    public Integer getDvrTypes() {
        return dvrTypes;
    }

    public void setDvrTypes(Integer dvrTypes) {
        this.dvrTypes = dvrTypes;
    }

    public Integer getDvrChannel() {
        return dvrChannel;
    }

    public void setDvrChannel(Integer dvrChannel) {
        this.dvrChannel = dvrChannel;
    }

    public Object getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(Object notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public Object getDeletedAt() {
        return deletedAt;
    }

    public void setDeletedAt(Object deletedAt) {
        this.deletedAt = deletedAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public CameraType getCameraType() {
        return cameraType;
    }

    public void setCameraType(CameraType cameraType) {
        this.cameraType = cameraType;
    }

    public DvrType getDvrType() {
        return dvrType;
    }

    public void setDvrType(DvrType dvrType) {
        this.dvrType = dvrType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("id", id).append("customerId", customerId).append("serviceTypeId", serviceTypeId).append("fullName", fullName).append("email", email).append("addressLine1", addressLine1).append("addressLine2", addressLine2).append("phoneNo", phoneNo).append("alternatePhoneNo", alternatePhoneNo).append("landMark", landMark).append("area", area).append("district", district).append("city", city).append("state", state).append("pincode", pincode).append("typeOfProperty", typeOfProperty).append("cameraTypes", cameraTypes).append("noOfCameras", noOfCameras).append("dvrTypes", dvrTypes).append("dvrChannel", dvrChannel).append("notes", notes).append("deletedAt", deletedAt).append("createdAt", createdAt).append("updatedAt", updatedAt).append("cameraType", cameraType).append("dvrType", dvrType).toString();
    }


}
```

[image: Unable to iterate JSON]

Comment: Can you share your POJO class? And what problem are you having?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Forgot to paste it. I have added it to question

Comment: I have added to the end of the question

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai getCamera_type()/getDvr_type() shows error - Cannot resolve method. It is checking the OrderDetailsResponse for the method . I have added picture

Comment: What does `OrderDetailsGet` look like?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Added OrderDetailsGet, Sorry for the delay. Was away from internet for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to the the name from `camera_type` and `dvr_type`, you can do:

```
//This assumes that you have a getCameraType & getDvrTypes method in your OrderDetailsGet class
String camera_name = orderDetails.getData().get(0).getCameraType().getName()
String dvr_name = orderDetails.getData().get(0).getDvrTypes().getName()
```

Comment: getCamera_type()/getDvr_type()  shows error - Cannot resolve method. It is checking the OrderDetailsResponse for the method.